# Check if item with same name but different values is already in list

Tags: for-loop

I have a list of objects called BasketItem. The BasketItem's have different properties, title, id and format. I add BasketItems to a list however when two BasketItems of the same title/id but different formats are added I want to change its Price property to 0.

For instance, I have book1 and can add it in either MOBI or EPUB. If I add book1 in MOBI to my list the price is 3.99 so the total price is 3.99. If I then add EPUB I want the total to remain 3.99 however if I add it in with price of 0 if I removed book1-MOBI from the list the total value would be 0 since the remaining book has that property.

I need either the totalprice calulator to check or something else.

I tried with two for loops checking if ID were the same but format were different however I couldn't work out how to make it work.

Basket item properties:

```
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string ReferenceNumber { get; set; }
    public decimal UnitPrice { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string FormatType { get; set; }
    public int BaskID { get; set; }
    public bool AddedToBask { get; set; }
```

For a simpler exmaple: when I add to a basket I simple add a BasketItem to a list of BasketItems

I have a Basket property which calculates the total price:

```
                foreach (BasketItem item in BasketItems)
            {
                foreach (BasketItem bskItem in BasketItems)
                {
                    if(item == bskItem)
                    {
                        totalPrice += item.UnitPrice;
                    }
                }
            }
            return totalPrice;
```

When a item of the same Name/ID is in the basket you only pay one price for multiple formats.
Meaning you add book1-MOBI to the basket with price 3.99 so basket total goes to 3.99.
If you added book1-EPUB to the basket the total of the basket would stay 3.99 since it's just different format.
If you then added book2-MOBI it would go to 7.98 since 2 distinct books.

**Code from VB Comment in C#**

```
        public decimal BasketTotal {
        get {
            decimal totalPrice = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < BasketItems.Count; i++)
            {
                bool existsPre = false;
                for (int j = i; j >= 0; j--)
                {
                    if(BasketItems[i].Title == BasketItems[j].Title && BasketItems[i].FormatType != BasketItems[j].FormatType)
                    {
                        existsPre = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (!existsPre)
                {
                    totalPrice += BasketItems[i].UnitPrice;
                }
            }
            return totalPrice;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you simplify your example, and show some code examples?

Comment: Added the two loops and another example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this pseudocode (sorry, I think in VB.NET language):

```
For i as Integer = 0 To BasketItems.Count - 1

    Dim blnExistsAnotherFormat as Boolean = False

    For j as Integer = i To 0 Step -1
        If BasketItems(i).Title = BasketItems(j).Title And _
            BasketItems(i).FormatType <> BasketItems(j).FormatType Then
            blnExistsAnotherFormat = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next j

    If Not blnExistsAnotherFormat Then
        TotalPrice += BasketItems(i).UnitPrice
    End If

Next i
```

Comment: I added my c# code into my post however it works when I a single item in the basket or even two different items. But two of the same type different format doesn't work. I might be todo with the way I converted from VB to C#

Comment: the second loop must be a reverse loop that starts at the item you are analyzing. you also have to reset existsPre = false on every loop of the first foreach.

Comment: I reversed the list then filtered through in the second for loop but it still has the same error. It makes both have value of 0 and not one.

Comment: Posted I reversed the list i filter through

Comment: the reversed loop must start from the position you are analyzing; if you have a list of 10 items and you are analizying the 3th item you have only to check if the first two items contains the same title in a different format. sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Oh okay so it only analyzes ones the other for has checked I understand will update code now